# How to Modify the Contents of DIV with the same Parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

First post here.

I have a list of parent divs of theoretical length, n.
Within these parents are 'child' divs containing a select pulldown and an edit button respectively.

Upon clicking the edit button, I want to change the select pulldown to a standard text input field.

I've looked at a number of examples but have been unable to find the most appropriate solution. Perhaps it would be better to have the edit button within the same div as the select pulldown?

It also appears there is a problem with the event handler.
Suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks.

HTML below:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="test">

    <div class="choose">
        <select class = "tag"><option value='gain'>gain</option><option value='share'>share</option><option value='bring'>bring</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="edit-button">
        <a href="#" data-action="edit">edit</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="test">

    <div class="choose">
        <select class = "tag"><option value='gain'>gain</option><option value='share'>share</option><option value='bring'>bring</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="edit-button">
        <a href="#" data-action="edit">edit</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="test">

    <div class="choose">
        <select class = "tag"><option value='gain'>gain</option><option value='share'>share</option><option value='bring'>bring</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="edit-button">
        <a href="#" data-action="edit">edit</a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var multiTags = $("#multi");

        function handler(e) {
            // get the element which trigged the event
            var jqEl = $(e.currentTarget);

            // get parent div
            var tag = jqEl.parent();

            // check which action we should perform
            switch (jqEl.attr("data-action")) {

            case "edit":

                var tag = tag.parent();
                $(this).tag.html('<input type="text" id="something"/>');

                break;

            }

            return false;
        }

    multiTags.find("a").live("click", handler);
});



</script>
```

Comment: have you tried using .on instead of .live?

Comment: `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. You should switch to `.on`.

Comment: My bad, there's no need for #multi reference. Forgot to strip that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
$(".edit-button").on("click", "a[data-action=edit]", function() {
    var testDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
    var selectValue = testDiv.find(".choose").find("select").val();
    var input = "<input name='' value='" + selectValue + "'/>";
    testDiv.find(".choose").html(input);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WxPPR/

Comment: Thanks for offering this solution. Far more elegant. I was writing my own subroutines in comparison...